# How do popular JS Wysiwyg editor access style of copy-pasted webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I don't understand how wysiwyg such as Froala or Redactor, are able to render into proper HTML, something that you just copied from another webpage (and that would have rendered only as text if you pasted it somewhere else).

If you want to checkout the behavior I am talking about, just

1. go to this page : https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor
2. then delete all the demo content in the editor
3. then copy some article on medium, wikipedia or whatever
4. Then paste it in the editor

You can see it is rendered as proper HTML (you can switch their editor to see the actual html behind) : bold is still bold, titles are titles, etc, as if the editor was somehow able to access the style of the copied page.

How do they access to this style ?

Comment: It is actually the browser that creates the html code you get. The different editors might add/remove/change the code after. So it is up to what your browser support of "past html content"

Comment: I suspect the os to be responsible for storing HTML in the clipboard somehow, because it works also if you copy from safari to chrome. But if you display the clipboard (easy in Mac Finder > Edit > Show Clipboard), you see only text stored... !

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the guys who is working on the Froala Editor. The browser is doing most of the jobs in terms of placing the right style there in the browser clipboard object. We're just getting the style from the browser clipboard when the HTML gets pasted to the editor.